# C# Decimal Format 123.123,44 with Rounding

Tags: format, decimal, rounding

I need correct sample of using decimal format and decimal rounding to  closest integer.

Sample1:  I have number 123.345,51    result need to be 123.346,00

Sample2:  I have number 123.345,49    result need to be 123.345,00

I found samples but they all use format with comma first 123,345.00  I need in first place point like 123.345,00

Tried with culture info but did not success  ..

Sample code:

```
var amount = 123.345,77;
var cultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("da-DK");
var formattedAmount = String.Format(cultureInfo, "{0:C}", amount);
```

When I need to convert formattedAmount  to decimal its breaks... I am converting for Rounding values after ,

Comment: Please show exactly *what* you tried with CultureInfo... perhaps you were specifying an inappropriate culture.

Comment: Hi Jon,   look at updated sample

Comment: The code you've posted won't compile, and it's not clear what you mean by "When I need to convert formattedAmount to decimal it breaks" - do you *actually* need the formatted value at all, or is this *just* for the sake of rounding? If it's all about rounding, don't go via string at all...

Comment: I am getting from textbox  values like 123.345,55  and I need to have final value result as 123.346,00 rounding last two digit ,55 to first integer.

Comment: Do you need to have that final value as a decimal, or as a string? Have you already managed to do the parsing?

Comment: I would like to have final result as decimal. No,  I have problem with parsing any value that looks like 123.345,55.

Comment: So we can actually take the string handling out of this completely, right? You want rounding from 123345.55m to 123346.00m. Do you actually care whether it's that or just 123346?

Comment: Rounding to closest integer if  value after coma is .55  like 123345.55  result need to be 123346. Also, I need to use colon ,  instead of coma .  as divider

Comment: You're getting confused between the *textual representation* and the *number being represented*. A `decimal` value doesn't have any notion of what format it's using - it's just a number. Also note that a colon is `:`, a comma is `,` and a dot is `.`.

Comment: Yes,  You are correct Jon.  I mean dot .  Yes,  like I am seeing now that displaying format and decimal format are not the same.   You are helped me a lot with this.  Thanks,  I think I know what to do now.

Comment: Right, so we're making progress - do you *actually* care about the formatting any more, or are you really just looking for `Math.Round`?

Comment: Now ,  I will do only rounding on input number, and for formatting I'll allow user to use format they wish like 123.123,45

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean - but I don't think it's a good idea to go any further in this comment thread. I suggest you think about this a bit more carefully, read up on `Math.Round(decimal, int)` and then edit this question to be clearer if you still need help.

Comment: I will thank you Jon,  this was helpful .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to enable users to input in format they want, like  123123,55 then use .Replace(",", ".") to replace , colon character with dot, after that made Decimal.Round and all problem are solved!